# Shortcut to terminal/bash script without 'instant close'

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I've created a desktop entry in `~/.local/share/applications`. It looks similiar to the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Crontona Server
GenericName=CA Server
Comment=BDAF server for Crontona
Exec=bash "/usr/local/crontona/run.sh"
Icon=/usr/local/crontona/app.ico
Terminal=true
Type=Application
```

It show's up in the Unity launcher and everything, but whenever I click it, the terminal just pops up but instantly closes. I have no problems at all with using 'bash ./.....run.sh' but I've had no success through the menu. Any idea why it happens?

This is the content of the run.sh file:

```
#!/bin/bash
./corona_run -prot tcp +maxcon 16
```

Comment: What happens if you just use `Exec=/usr/local/crontona/run.sh` ?

Comment: Hmm... "There was an error creating the child process for this terminal. Failed to execute child process `/usr/local/crontona/run.sh` (Permission denied)". Seems like a permission problem... Then, how do I execute 'with' permission through a desktop shortcut?

Comment: Perhaps "run.sh" is not executable? What does `ls -la /usr/local/crontona/run.sh` say?

Comment: Perhaps you need `Exec=sudo /usr/local/crontona/run.sh` -- I'm not familiar with these, so I don't know if you need quotes.

Comment: Hmm... weird. When I have 'sudo' in front, it asks for my password when I start the shortcut, but then instantly closes? Makes no sense...

Comment: @SirCharlo -rwxrwxr-x 1 chora chora 76 May  7 21:15 /usr/local/crontona/run.sh

Comment: Ok.. Does the "run.sh" file have the appropriate shebang and path to the bash interpreter on the first line? For example: `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: Nope, but it still crashed instantly after I added that :( Don't know what you mean by 'shebang' though.

Comment: closed* not crashed

Comment: The shebang is the `#!` :) What happens when you simply run this from the command prompt: `/usr/local/crontona/run.sh`? If an error message is output this could help greatly.

Comment: @SirCharlo That's the thing. It works perfectly fine even with our without 'bash' in front, if I do it through the terminal. But if I do it through the unity menu, it instantly closes. Perhaps there is some output but there is no way I can read that in time.

Comment: Can we see the contents of `run.sh` please? Also, you could try adding `sleep 15` after the last line of your code.. It should make the script wait fifteen seconds before closing, and perhaps give you time to read any error messages.

Comment: @SirCharlo of course! I've edited the original post.

Comment: On a side-note, you should avoid putting extensions on commands; especially not `.sh` when it's not an sh script. Extensions just cause dependency headaches if you rewrite it in another language. Also, the user won't care what language it's written in as long as the command does what it's documented to do.

Answer (score 0):

Add the command `read x` as the last line in run.sh.  This read will cause the command window to remain open until you press return.  If any messages are displayed this gives time to read them.

---

The `read` is the key.  Here is a shell script (I prefer it to bash although bash is becoming as popular).  BTW, the .sh at the end means shell script, not script.
You could change your launcher Exec option to:

```
Exec="/usr/local/crontona/run.sh"
```

And use the following run.sh script...

```
#!/bin/sh
./corona_run -prot tcp +maxcon 16
echo -n Press enter to end...
read x
echo Ending Now\!
```

Notice I escaped the ! in the Ending Now.  That last line is not needed unless you are running the script inside a terminal and want to have it echo execution.  This way, if the terminal appears and the script is run inside the terminal, the script will not exit until you press enter so the terminal cannot close until you are ready.

Comment: Or, in the .desktop-file, `Exec=bash -c '/path/to/script; read -p "Hit enter to close"'`